# Bluetooth Mouse need to re-connect every time I restart. How to add it permanently?

Tags: 14.04, mouse, bluetooth

I have a Logitech Bluetooth Mouse M557. It works with my Ubuntu but I need to re-enable it every time I restart my laptop and reach to desktop. Also it doesn't work on Login screen.

Answer (score 2):

```
hcitool scan  # it will find MAC of the mouse
sudo bluez-simple-agent hci0 <MAC>
sudo bluez-test-device trusted <MAC> yes
sudo bluez-test-input connect <MAC>
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue (right down to the same type of mouse) and hcitool scan doesn't pick anything up.  Any alternatives?

Cheers!

Comment: For this to work you have to remove your mouse from the bluetooth list (if it's already connected) and make it discoverable.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with Bluez. Same issue exists on Debian 7.8 (bluez package 4.99-2). On Debian 8.0 RC1 (bluez package 5.23-2) it works, however still some warning shown for mouse:

```
[   43.710930] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[   43.710940] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[   43.852388] hid-generic 0005:046D:B010.0001: unknown main item tag 0x0
[   43.852490] input: Bluetooth Mouse M557 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:046D:B010.0001/input/input20
[   43.852692] hid-generic 0005:046D:B010.0001: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v10.01 Mouse [Bluetooth Mouse M557] on 74:f0:6d:a7:00:1e
```

So solution would be to upgrade Bluez and other dependencies.